# Python- Assertion error when performing nosetests

Tags: python-2.7, web.py

I am new to web.py . I was following  ex52 LPTHW , and I had to perform nosetests on all the tests in tests folder. But I am getting 1 failed test due to assertion error. I tried reading different assertion errors and why they occur , but I cant figure out this one. I tried expanding the errors which the server could possibly show up like 500 Internal , 400 but its still failing the test. I have created the other code just like mentioned in the book: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex52.html

Here is my traceback:

```
C:\lpthw\gothonweb>cd tests

C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests>nosetests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\bin\app.py", line 29, in GET
    return render.hello_form()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\template.py", line 1017, in __getattr__
    t = self._template(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\template.py", line 1014, in _template
    return self._load_template(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\template.py", line 1001, in _load_template
    raise AttributeError, "No template named " + name
AttributeError: No template named hello_form

F...
======================================================================
FAIL: tests.app_tests.test_index
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests\app_tests.py", line 12, in test_index
    assert_response(resp)
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests\tools.py", line 5, in assert_response
    assert status in resp.status, "Expected response %r not in %r" % (status , resp.status)
AssertionError: Expected response '200' not in '500 Internal Server Error'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.562s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

My tests code: app_tests.py

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import app
from tests.tools import assert_response

def test_index():
    #check that we get a 404 on the / URL
    resp = app.request("/")
    assert_response(resp, status= "404")

    #test our first GET request to /hello
    resp = app.request("/hello")
    assert_response(resp)

    #make sure default values work for the form 
    resp = app.request("/hello" , method="POST")
    assert_response(resp , contains="Nobody")

    #test that we get expected values
    data = {'name':'Tejas','greet':'Ola!'}
    resp = app.request("/hello " , method= "POST", data=data)
    assert_response(resp , contains="Zed")
```

tools.py :

```
from nose.tools import *
import re

def assert_response(resp, contains=None, matches=None, headers=None, status= "200"):
    assert status in resp.status, "Expected response %r not in %r" % (status , resp.status)

    if status == "200":
        assert resp.data , "Response data is empty."

    if contains:
        assert contains in resp.data, "Response does not contain %r" % contains 

    if matches:
        reg = re.compile(matches)
        assert reg.matches(resp.data), "Response does not match %r" % matches 

    if headers:
        assert_equal(resp.headers , headers)
```

app.py code:

```
import web 
from gothonweb import map 

urls = (
       '/game' , 'GameEngine' ,
       '/' , 'Index',
        )

app = web.application(urls, globals())
#little hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store= web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session= web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'room':None})
    web.config._session = session 
else:
    session= web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")   

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        #this is used to "setup" the session with starting values
        session.room= map.START
        web.seeother("/game")

class GameEngine(object):
    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room= session.room)
        else:
            #why is there here? do you need it?
             return render.you_died()

    def POST(self):
        form= web.input(action=None)

        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room= session.room.go(form.action)
        else:
            session.room= None        


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run()
```

After going ahead with the exercise now it gives me 2 import errors:

```
PS C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests> nosetests
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (app.py, line 2))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests\app_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bin.app import app
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\bin\app.py", line 2
    from gothonweb import map.py
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name map)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests\map_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gothonweb import map
ImportError: cannot import name map

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=2)
```

directory structure:

```
C:/lpthw/
    gothonweb/
    bin build dist doc sessions Gothonweb templates tests map.py app.py 
tests/
map_tests.py
app_tests.py
__init__.py
tools.py
```

What should I do to fix the error? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: The AssertionError is not your problem, it is the AttributeError that you should be investigating.

Comment: More specifically, your error is at line 29 in app.py, code which you haven't provided.

Comment: I have updated it with app.py code but I think we had to change app.py ahead in the exercise which I have so it isnt the same app.py as before, as we had to add a few things.

Comment: Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Now when i run nosetests I get 2 errors: both giving import errors : cannot import map from gothonweb. I cant figure out whats wrong because the structure looks right to me and import statements are like the ones given in the book.

Comment: What are the files in your gothonweb directory?

Comment: RE the SynatxError, import statements do not require you reference the file extension, so replace `from gothonweb import map.py` with `from gothonweb import map`

Comment: even with map it is giving an import error : cannot import name map.

Comment: Create an `__init__.py` in your `gothonweb` directory. The file should be empty.

Comment: I also researched and realised that bin/ should also contain a __init__.py file , because it is not a package just a directory.

Comment: Sounds like progress! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this error,

> "AttributeError: No template named hello_form"

use an absolute path and see if that works, instead of

`"render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")`

try:

```
"render = web.template.render('C:/lpthw/gothonweb/bin/templates', base="layout")
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, your test has nothing to do with app.py.

```
from nose.tools import *
from bin.app import app
from tests.tools import assert_response

def test_index():
    #check that we get a 404 on the / URL
    resp = app.request("/")
    assert_response(resp, status= "404")

    #test our first GET request to /hello
    resp = app.request("/hello")
    assert_response(resp)

    #make sure default values work for the form 
    resp = app.request("/hello" , method="POST")
    assert_response(resp , contains="Nobody")

    #test that we get expected values
    data = {'name':'Tejas','greet':'Ola!'}
    resp = app.request("/hello " , method= "POST", data=data)
    assert_response(resp , contains="Zed")
```

App.py

```
import web 
from gothonweb import map 

urls = (
       '/game' , 'GameEngine' ,
       '/' , 'Index',
        )

app = web.application(urls, globals())
#little hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store= web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session= web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'room':None})
    web.config._session = session 
else:
    session= web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")   

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        #this is used to "setup" the session with starting values
        session.room= map.START
        web.seeother("/game")

class GameEngine(object):
    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room= session.room)
        else:
            #why is there here? do you need it?
             return render.you_died()

    def POST(self):
        form= web.input(action=None)

        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room= session.room.go(form.action)
        else:
            session.room= None        


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run()
```

Can you see, how they are not related

Your first test says you should get a 404 on the '/' url but that would only happen if '/' didn't exist. Your app.py code clearly shows that '/' calls on GET in the Index class.

Second test, `resp = app.request("/hello")` now that would give you a 404 error because that url doesn't exist on app.py

The same goes for the third test as '/hello' doesn't exist in your tuple of urls in app.py

And the fifth test as well

Although your tests are invalid, the primary problem you have though is trying to perform the automated test from inside the tests directory; that's wrong.

```
C:\lpthw\gothonweb\tests> nosetests
```

This is not the right thing to do, you need to be a directory below for all your imports to work e.g In app_tests you are trying to import bin/app.py but that's not in the 'tests' directory

Do this instead

```
C:\lpthw\gothonweb> nosetests
```

This way all the files that you need would be imported
Back to app_tests.py. I'll write out a very simple test that's actually related to app.py

```
 from bin.app import app
 from test.tools import assert_response

def test_index():
    #check that we get a 303 on the / url
    #this is because web.seeother() will always send the browser this http code
    resp = app.request("/")
    assert_response(resp, status= "303")

def test_game():
    #check that we get a 200 on /game
    resp = app.request("/game")
    assert_response(resp, status = '200')

    #check that we have response data on a form sumbit
    resp = app.request("/game", method = 'POST')
    aseert_response(resp.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The assertion_error you getting because your ran `nosetests` in this directory

**/gothroweb/test**

you should run it in 
**/gothroweb**

```
bin  docs  gothonweb  templates  tests

./bin:
app.py  app.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc

./docs:

./gothonweb:
__init__.py  __init__.pyc

./templates:
hello_form.html  index.html  layout.html

./tests:
app_tests.py   __init__.py   test.html  tools.pyc
app_tests.pyc  __init__.pyc  tools.py
```

cheers